# 'Unicode' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I am using Cassandra DB and Django Framework, I was trying to get the partial information of a particular user from the database and tried to compare it to the user input but instead of returning an output, it showed me a "Unicode object has no attribute items" error

This is the error details for your reference:

**Error Details**

```
AttributeError at /auth-user-session/

'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth-user-session/
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py in last_executed_query, line 215
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/home/chamber/Desktop/Emergency-Command-Center-SOFTDEV/Application/Emergency-Command-Center',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/chamber/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

Server time:    Tue, 14 Mar 2017 08:08:05 +0000
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth-user-session/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django_cassandra_engine',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'gentelella.core']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/chamber/Desktop/Emergency-Command-Center-SOFTDEV/Application/Emergency-Command-Center/gentelella/core/views.py" in LoginAuthPageView
  79.             result = cursor.execute("SELECT salt, password FROM emergency_command_center.auth_user_model WHERE username = ?", username)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  83.             sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py" in last_executed_query
  215.             u_params = {to_unicode(k): to_unicode(v) for k, v in params.items()}

Exception Type: AttributeError at /auth-user-session/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'
```

This is the code:

**views.py**

```
def LoginAuthPageView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Login(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.data['username']
            password = form.data['password']

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute("SELECT salt, password FROM emergency_command_center.auth_user_model WHERE username = ?", username)

            pword_hash = hashlib.sha512(password + result['salt']).hexdigest()

            if(pword_hash == result['password']):
                return HttpResponse(pword_hash)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Error stack trace is misleading. Can you edit the same. We need to know at which line the error is occurring then only it ll be easy to debug.

Comment: Does your query result any rows? seems null handling issue where result['salt'] does not have value

Comment: I already added the Error Traceback, hope it'll help

Comment: @PriyankMehta result['salt'] is not null and has a value

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors - Django cursors use the `%s` placeholder

Comment: @Kendas replacing ? with %s placeholder gave me ValueError

Comment: @Chamber The `execute` method apparently expects a `tuple`, `list` or `dict` as the `params` argument so try `[username]` or `(username,)`

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL rather than Django models?

Comment: @Kendas so the code will become `cursor.execute("SELECT salt, password FROM emergency_command_center.auth_user_model WHERE [username] = %s", username)`? If so, it just resulted to the first error I encountered

Comment: @Chamber `cursor.execute("SELECT salt, password FROM emergency_command_center.auth_user_model WHERE username = %s", (username,))` or `cursor.execute("SELECT salt, password FROM emergency_command_center.auth_user_model WHERE username = %(username)s", {"username": username})`

Comment: @Kendas the code you suggested gave me this error `InvalidRequest at /auth-user-session/

Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"`

Comment: It could be that you specified some param like `param = "value"` and it should be like `param = ["value",]`. I'd advise you to check.

Comment: @Flan sorry for the late response, I also already tried that but the problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

The question is somewhat aged by now, but people might still find it when searching for the error-message: "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'"

In my case (youtube-dl), using python3 instead of python2 solved it.

Maybe one of the involved .py files just uses a python3-ism.

Comment: Are you using mac os? If so, how did you get youtube-dl to use python3?

Comment: I'm on Linux.  youtube-dl is a binary file, but its first line is "#!/usr/bin/env python", so it picks python from the PATH.   All I did was to add a link named python, pointing to python3 to a directory that youtube-dl would find before the default "python"(that is version 2)

Comment: Maybe further clarification:  my system has /usr/bin/python version 2.7.17 and /usr/bin/python3 version 3.6.9 .   All I did was "ln -s /usr/bin/python3 ~/bin/python" and make sure that ~/bin is in $PATH before /usr/bin .